# How to only pass strings that the user select

Tags: java, android

When i click a button i need the button to pass only the selected String.

I try to pass a specific string if a Integer is 2.

show that's my first activity called PlayerChoose:

```
    //PI1 and PI2 is Strings from another Activity.
    PI1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Player1Text");
    PI2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Player2Text");

    //These bellow are buttons.
    Player1Btn = findViewById(R.id.PlayerToD1);
    Player2Btn = findViewById(R.id.PlayerToD2);

    //These Integers is to set 0 so the app is not broken.
    PlayerInt1 = 0;
    PlayerInt2 = 0;

    //Here im setting text to the buttons so you know what player you pick
    Player1Btn.setText(PI1);
    Player2Btn.setText(PI2);

    //These button adds 1 to the Integer PlayerInt1 so if you hit it 
    //twice it executes what is in the if statement.
    Player1Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlayerInt1++;
            if (PlayerInt1 == 2) {
    Intent TruthOrDare1 = new Intent(PlayerChoose.this,TruthOrDare.class);
                TruthOrDare1.putExtras(getIntent());
                TruthOrDare1.putExtra("Player1Text", PI1);
                startActivity(TruthOrDare1);
            }
        }
    });
    //Same button as Player1Btn Does the same things.
    Player2Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlayerInt2++;
            if (PlayerInt2 == 2) {
    Intent TruthOrDare2 = new Intent(PlayerChoose.this,TruthOrDare.class);
                TruthOrDare2.putExtras(getIntent());
                TruthOrDare2.putExtra("Player2Text", PI2);
                startActivity(TruthOrDare2);
            }
        }
    });

    }
 }
```

Here is my second activity called TruthOrDare:

```
    //PI1 Should take what i passed with "Player1Text" and save it as a 
    //String
    //PI2 Should take what i passed with "Player2Text" and save it as a 
    //String
    PI1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Player1Text");
    PI2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("Player2Text");


    //PlayerTurnName1 and PlayerTurnName2 is textviews 
    PlayerTurnName1 = findViewById(R.id.PlayerTurnText1);
    PlayerTurnName2 = findViewById(R.id.PlayerTurnText2);

    //Here i set text to textview whatever have been passes PI1 or PI2
    //Depending
    PlayerTurnName1.setText(PI1);
    PlayerTurnName2.setText(PI2);
```

My problem is that it passes both Strings PI1,PI2 instead of PI1 only if i hit Player1Btn in PlayerChoose Activity and PI2 if i hit Player2Btn.How can i pass only PI1 if i click Player1Btn and PI2 if i hit PI2.

Comment: May I know, the TextViewP2 should display the value if the user pressed the button for the Player1Btn?

Comment: whatever button i hit 1 or 2 it set text to PI2 i try adding 3 button to see if thats the problem and it set to PI3 so it just sets to the last value i pass

Comment: Not sure why this line: `TruthOrDare2.putExtras(getIntent());` - this puts both `"Player1Text"` and `"Player2Text"` back into the intent along with the textfield text when returning to second activity,  using the same keys.

Comment: I want to only pass what the choose to pass if he click Player1Btn only pass PI1 and if He click Player2Btn only pass PI2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have unnecessary strings

```
TruthOrDare1.putExtras(getIntent());
TruthOrDare2.putExtras(getIntent());
```

in click listeners, which adds both PI1 & PI2

Comment: i find another way to do the same thing i will post it as an answer but if you have a other way you can post it

Comment: Have you tried this way, just removing unnecessary code?

Comment: Why is these code unnecessary?I really dont know i learn that from Youtube so i do it like i saw it

Comment: Look i'm gonna use my code because i need to pass somethink else that like have same name but if you're sure i can make your question to be the right one and i will read what everythink do in the future.

Comment: I see what you did there in your solution. It is a bad approach when you really don't know what is happening. There is still no need in these two lines. Just try to refer more to documentation than just blindly copying code from some youtube vid. Anyway its great that you were able to make your app working!

Answer (score 0):

So its simple in the first activity named PlayerChoose you can make another String named whatever im gonna name it PIP1 for the example so thats what you have to do:

```
  //So Put PI1 as default string of PIP1.
  PIP1 = PI1;
  //Then in the Buttons OnClickListeners 
  Player1Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlayerInt1++;
            //If you click this button it will set PIP1 to the string you want to 
            //pass in this case PI1
            PIP1 = PI1;
            if (PlayerInt1 == 2) {
          Intent TruthOrDare1 = new Intent(PlayerChoose.this, TruthOrDare.class);
                TruthOrDare1.putExtras(getIntent());
                //Intead of putting the text itself you put PIP1 thats changing 
                //depens on what button you click
                TruthOrDare1.putExtra("PlayerText", PIP1);
                startActivity(TruthOrDare1);
            }
        }
    });
    Player2Btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlayerInt2++;
            //And here you Change the same string PIP1 to PI2
            //Here you change the PIP1 to PI2 so PIP1 change to PI2 and not PI1
            PIP1 = PI2;
            if (PlayerInt2 == 2) {
           Intent TruthOrDare2 = new Intent(PlayerChoose.this, TruthOrDare.class);
                TruthOrDare2.putExtras(getIntent());
                TruthOrDare2.putExtra("PlayerText", PIP1);
                startActivity(TruthOrDare2);
            }
        }
    });
```

In the second Activity called TruthOrDare You change this:

```
    //So you only have 1 String Instead of 2 with 1 key 
    PI1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("PlayerText");


    //One TextView
    PlayerTurnName1 = findViewById(R.id.PlayerTurnText1);



    PlayerTurnName1.setText(PI1);
```

The concept is that PIP1 changes every time you hit the button so its not passing all the values.